# Unable to install ruby in MACOS Sierra

Tags: ruby, macos

```
ruby-build: use openssl from homebrew
Downloading ruby-2.4.2.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.4/ruby-2.4.2.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.4.2...
ruby-build: use readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.12.6 using ruby-build 20170914)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20170926231141.40401
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20170926231141.40401.log

Last 10 log lines:
Generating RDoc documentation
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _utimensat
  Referenced from: /private/tmp/ruby-build.20170926231141.40401/ruby-2.4.2/./ruby
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _utimensat
  Referenced from: /private/tmp/ruby-build.20170926231141.40401/ruby-2.4.2/./ruby
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

make: *** [rdoc] Abort trap: 6
```